# Input text in react form component does not allow text entry

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to react, and following a tutorial, made this Registration form (I just changed Bootstrap html with Materialize)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {          
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {}
        };

          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
       [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    });
  }

    render() {
        return (

        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s10 m6 offset-s1 offset-m3 ">

                <form className="col s12 myform">
                <h3 className="center"Register </h3>
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <input 
                                id="email" 
                                type="email" 
                                value={this.state.email} 
                                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                                />
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                       <div className="row">
                          <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <input 
                                id="password" 
                                type="password" 
                                value={this.state.password} 
                                onChange = {this.handleChange}  
                                />
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <button className="btn mybtn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                                <i className="mdi-content-send right"></i>
                              </button>
              </form>
            </div>  
          </div>    
        </div>



            );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

The problem is that I can not enter anything into the form and get no error in the console. So got really preplexed. Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written:

```
handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
       [e.target.name] : e.target.value // This line I mean.
    });
  }
```

So you just need to assign name prop to input tag because you have written e.target.name and your input name is available in the state but not available in input props.

So do it like this:
- Email input

```
<input 
    name="email"
    id="email" 
    type="email" 
    value={this.state.email} 
    onChange = {this.handleChange}
 />
```

- Password input

```
<input 
    name="email"
    id="email" 
    type="email" 
    value={this.state.email} 
    onChange = {this.handleChange}
 />
```

I hope it will be helped you and enjoy of react

Comment: I did assign `onChange = {this.handleChange}` to each field. What exactly need to be changed?

Comment: You don't need to change onChange hook, just you need to assign name prop to each input tag that assigned name should be equated with react state properties.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks for the tip!